# Rename individual values

Tags: python, pandas

The code below shows me all the cities that appeared in the dataset less than 10 times.

```
df[df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('count')<10]
```

How can I change the name of all these cities (which appeared less than 10 times) to 'other'?

the only thing that comes to my mind is a 'manual' change using replace as below but it would take a lot of time

```
df['city'] = df['city'].str.lower().str.replace('city_name1', 'other')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df[col].value_counts()[df[col]].values < 10, col] = "other"
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusing your code, you may use `df.mask`

```
df['city'] = df.city.mask(df.groupby('city')['city'].transform('count')<10, 'other')
```